# vim automatically show left tab after closing tab

Tags: vim

After closing a tab in vim, how do I make it so that the tab to the left is the one automatically shown?

The default when closing a tab seems to be showing the right tab, which is annoying because new tabs OPEN on the right of your current tab.  So opening a new tab and closing it leaves you on a different tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim8 or Vim9 with the following snippet in ~/.vimrc works for me.

```
autocmd TabClosed * tabprevious
```

Comment: oh sweet yes almost 11 years later my question has an actually good answer lol.  thx u works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

There is one idea: though there is no `TabClose` event there is `TabEnter` event which could be used to achieve what you want: if on one of the events number of tabs is less then previously recorded number then obviously it was triggered due to closed tab:

```
let s:prevtabnum=tabpagenr('$')
augroup TabClosed
    autocmd! TabEnter * :if tabpagenr('$')<s:prevtabnum && tabpagenr()>1
                \       |   tabprevious
                \       |endif
                \       |let s:prevtabnum=tabpagenr('$')
augroup END
```

Comment: @CiroSantilli You should really read all answers here. This link was already posted by OP in his own answer a year ago.

Answer (score 3):

A patch has been proposed to [add a 'tabcloseleft' option](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/ddfab45899a51de8); it is on the todo list to be integrated into Vim (some time in the future, once Bram has time to work on it).

Comment: Yep that's my patch, added several months back. Hopefully it makes it into the mainline soon.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, struggled with it for a while here is my solution.

Add the following to your `.vimrc` file. Note that I have remapped for the commands `:q` and `:Q`

```
" declare function for moving left when closing a tab.
function! TabCloseLeft(cmd)
    if winnr('$') == 1 && tabpagenr('$') > 1 && tabpagenr() > 1 && tabpagenr() < tabpagenr('$')
        exec a:cmd | tabprevious
    else
        exec a:cmd
    endif
endfunction

" define :Q command
command Q call TabCloseLeft('q!')

" override default quit command
cabbrev q <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'Q' : 'q')<CR>
```

credit for `TabCloseLeft` function: https://github.com/convissor/vim-settings/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it; there isn't any way that I can see. There isn't even an autocommand event that you could latch on to (e.g. `TabClose` would be what you would want, but it doesn't exist).

The closest you'll get is probably having your own command or mapping which will, as well as closing the tab, execute the normal mode `gT`. (You might be able to get fancy in a function and detect the state of the windows and thus whether you wish to `gT` or not. That would require a little more thought and investigation.)

You can, of course, also investigate using another solution to tabs; here are a few:

- Use split windows
- Use the alternate file (see `CTRL-6`)
- Use the tag stack for moving between files (`CTRL-]` to move, `CTRL-T` to get back)

Answer (score 0):

This looks useful:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Have_focus_on_left_tab_after_tabclose

I think I'm going to modify it slightly to do this:

```
function! CloseSomething()
    if winnr("$") == 1 && tabpagenr("$") > 1 && tabpagenr() > 1 && tabpagenr() < tabpagenr("$")
        q | tabprev
    else
        q
    endif
endfunction
cnoremap q<CR> :call CloseSomething()<CR>
```

So now `:q` will do what I want...

Comment: I like the concepts of this function and mapping, but it has shortcomings.  It would be nice to come up with something that also handles `quit`, `q!`, `wq`.  Even sweeter would be handling `x`, `ZZ` etc.  I tried many variations and couldn't get something working.